Changing QTableWidget header column width but other row column width and positon won't update width immediately - Qt C++
Describe question
Hello everyone, I'm developing an application using Qt 5.15 and C++ 17, which includes a QTableWidget.
I want to ensure that when the user adjusts the width of a column header in the table, the widths of the corresponding entire columns and the positions of subsequent columns are updated immediately.
However, I've noticed that if my QTableWidget uses setCellWidget(), the widths and positions of columns in the corresponding rows are not updated immediately when I drag the mouse, but only after releasing the mouse button.
How can I solve this problem so that the widths and positions of columns in rows are updated immediately when adjusting the width of a column header?
code
auto pTableWidget = ui.tableWidget;

const QStringList m_kHeaders = {
    "Column 1",
    "Column 2",
    "Column 3"
};

pTableWidget->clearContents();
pTableWidget->setRowCount( 0 );
pTableWidget->setColumnCount( m_kHeaders.size() );
pTableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels( m_kHeaders );

QHeaderView* pHeaderView = pTableWidget->horizontalHeader();
pHeaderView->resizeSection( 0,  60 );
pHeaderView->resizeSection( 1, 180 );
pHeaderView->setStretchLastSection( true );

for ( int row = 0; row < 5; ++row )
{
    size_t uRowCount = pTableWidget->rowCount();
    pTableWidget->insertRow( uRowCount );

    for ( int col = 0; col < 3; ++col )
    {
        QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget;
        QHBoxLayout* pLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
        pLayout->setContentsMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
        pLayout->setAlignment( Qt::AlignCenter );
        pLayout->setSizeConstraint( QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize );
        pWidget->setLayout( pLayout );

        QString strText = QString( "( %1, %2 )" )
            .arg( QString::number( row ) )
            .arg( QString::number( col ) );

        QLabel* pLabel = new QLabel;
        pLabel->setText( strText );

        pLayout->addWidget( pLabel );
        pTableWidget->setCellWidget( row, col, pWidget );
    }
}

result
and the final result (Only update column width when I released the mouse):

The methods that I tried
Using sectionResized event
I have attempted to receive the QHeaderView::sectionResized event. When I drag the column to update its width, I iterate through all rows and columns, find the corresponding QWidget, and directly modify their width.
code
// connect event when Initialize...
QHeaderView* pHeaderView = pTableWidget->horizontalHeader();
connect( pHeaderView, &QHeaderView::sectionResized, this, &QtWidgetsApplication1::OnTableWidgetHeaderResize );

// resize event impl
void QtWidgetsApplication1::OnTableWidgetHeaderResize( int nLogicalIndex, int nOldSize, int nNewSize )
{
    auto pTableWidget = ui.tableWidget;

    QHeaderView* pHeaderView = pTableWidget->horizontalHeader();

    pTableWidget->blockSignals( true );
    pHeaderView->blockSignals( true );

    int nColumnCount = pTableWidget->columnCount();
    if ( nLogicalIndex >= nColumnCount || nLogicalIndex < 0 )
    {
        return;
    }

    int nRowCount = pTableWidget->rowCount();
    for ( int nRow = 0; nRow < nRowCount; ++nRow ) {
        auto pCellWidget = pTableWidget->cellWidget( nRow, nLogicalIndex );
        if ( pCellWidget )
        {
            pCellWidget->setFixedWidth( nNewSize );
        }
    }

    pTableWidget->resizeRowsToContents();
    pTableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents();

    pTableWidget->blockSignals( false );
    pHeaderView->blockSignals( false );
}

result
Although it works, the problem is that the starting positions of their columns are not updated.
The result is as shown in the following image:

Use QTreeWidget to replace QTableWidget
Then I found that I can avoid this issue by use QTreeWidget to replace QTableWidget; However, I need to make the treewidget looks like a "table".
I think this is not a elegant solution, but at least it's a workaround.
code
auto pTreeWidget = ui.treeWidget;

const QStringList m_kHeaders = {
    "Column 1",
    "Column 2",
    "Column 3"
};

pTreeWidget->clear();
pTreeWidget->setColumnCount( m_kHeaders.size() );
pTreeWidget->setHeaderLabels( m_kHeaders );

QHeaderView* pHeaderView = pTreeWidget->header();
pHeaderView->resizeSection( 0,  60 );
pHeaderView->resizeSection( 1, 180 );
pHeaderView->setStretchLastSection( true );
pHeaderView->setDefaultAlignment( Qt::AlignCenter );

for ( int row = 0; row < 5; ++row )
{
    QTreeWidgetItem* pItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    pTreeWidget->addTopLevelItem( pItem );

    for ( int col = 0; col < 3; ++col )
    {
        QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget;
        QHBoxLayout* pLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
        pLayout->setContentsMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
        pLayout->setAlignment( Qt::AlignCenter );
        pLayout->setSizeConstraint( QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize );
        pWidget->setLayout( pLayout );

        QString strText = QString( "( %1, %2 )" )
            .arg( QString::number( row ) )
            .arg( QString::number( col ) );

        QLabel* pLabel = new QLabel;
        pLabel->setText( strText );
        pLabel->setFixedSize( pLabel->sizeHint().width(), 30 );
        pLayout->addWidget( pLabel );
        
        pTreeWidget->setItemWidget( pItem, col, pWidget );
    }
}
pTreeWidget->setStyleSheet( "QTreeView::item { border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8; border-right: 1px solid #D8D8D8; }" );

result
This is what I execpted... Should I use QTreeWidget to replace my QTableWidget in this case or there are some perfect solution could fix my problem?


It seems a regression introduced in 5.15 (see QTBUG-85484). Unfortunately, as far as I can understand, unless you have access to the LTS of Qt 5.15 (or maybe rebuild Qt on your own? not sure if it was also applied to the open source version), I don't see an immediate way to fix this, unless you create a dedicated singleshot QTimer connected to the header's sectionResized() that would eventually call updateGeometries().

You should urgently upgrade to Qt6, as Qt 5.15 LTS has been on extended support for almost a year already. Regarding your workaround, the model/view framework means that you can swap between a QTableView and a QTreeView with nothing to fix: your workaround won't create extra work in the future. As for However, I need to make the treewidget looks like a "table", your solution already looks good. With more stylesheet'ing, you can make it look right when hovering your mouse over items / selecting items.

Thanks for answering my question. As mentioned before, this is a bug caused by Qt itself. I conclude there are only two solutions: updating Qt version to 5.15.9 or above, or using QTreeWidget as a replacement for the workaround.
